# ionic getting device information for ios does not work while same code works for Android

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, device, cordova-plugins

I am trying to find what type of ios device my code is running on (iPhone 4s or iPhone 5 etc).

Here are html and js codes that I have.
This is **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="DeviceController">
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Device Information</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="item">
            Manufacturer : {{manufacturer}}
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            Model : {{model}}
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            Platform : {{platform}}
          </li>
          <li class="item">
            UUID : {{uuid}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
 </ion-pane>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And here is my **app.js**:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('DeviceController', function($ionicPlatform, $scope, $cordovaDevice) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();
      $scope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer;
      $scope.model = device.model;
      $scope.platform = device.platform;
      $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
    });
  });
});
```

The code works fine on Android, and gets all the requested information including device type and Android version, etc. But on iPhone the information is empty and I do not get any info back with the same code.

Is there anything I need to change for ios?

Answer (score 1):

I think a better and working way to do this would be:

```
.controller('DeviceController', function($ionicPlatform, $scope) {

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
    $scope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer;
    $scope.model = device.model;
    $scope.platform = device.platform;
    $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
  }   

});
```

You do not need to define the variable `var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();`

You may also use your way of using `$ionicPlatform.ready()` the document listener is just a way I like to write it and see it but I would imagine you don't need the $scope.$apply() to anything.

Official documentation: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

**EDIT (Add my personal code which works by request)**

Do not mind if my module structure is a little different from yours.

So this is my **testController.js**

```
angular.module('testApp.testController', [])
  .controller('testController', function($scope) {

  'use strict';

  document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('device ready');
    $scope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer;
    $scope.model = device.model;
    $scope.platform = device.platform;
    $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
  }

});
```

And here is my **test.html**

```
<ion-view class="testview">
  <ion-content class="test-list">
    <div>Manufacturer: {{manufacturer}}</div>
    <div>Model: {{model}}</div>
    <div>Platform: {{platform}}</div>
    <div>UUID: {{uuid}}</div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Then I just run `ionic build ios` and run it on my device with xcode. It shows up all the information just fine. Also tested in Android and works too!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it, it doesn't work even for Android.

Comment: Sorry I might have missed the ngCordova part. My example should work when cordova-plugin device is installe with `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device` . Did you try it with your way of doing it but change the ionicPlatform.ready to document.addEventListener and remove the scope.$apply?

Comment: Yes I did try what you said: `Did you try it with your way of doing it but change the ionicPlatform.ready to document.addEventListener and remove the scope.$apply` but didn't work again.

Comment: Oh, that is strange. I tested my code and it worked for me. I have no more ideas why it would not work for you. I'm sorry I couldn't help. I will get back to you if something pops up in my mind.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you put both your html and JavaScript code that you tested, the complete thing in your answer maybe I have something wrong in my codes.

Comment: No problem at all. I updated my answer with my controller and html file. I'm using $stateProviders to attach the controller to a view. Hopefully you can get your issue resolved.